# Is there any limit on the number of Scheduled Tasks that can be created in MarkLogic?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, marklogic

Is there any limit on:

1. The **number of Scheduled Tasks** that can be **created in MarkLogic**?
2. The **number of Scheduled Tasks** that can **run at the same time**?

**Note**: It took me around 20 minutes to create 1000 Schedule tasks on 16 GB RAM machine in MarkLogic 7.

The following script was used to insert the Scheduled Tasks:

```xq
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
                  at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

for $i in 1 to 1000

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $group := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")

let $new-task :=
  admin:group-one-time-scheduled-task(
    "/tasks/write-log.xqy",
    "/",
    xs:dateTime("2014-10-27T11:40:00"),
    xdmp:database("SampleDB"),
    xdmp:database("Modules"),
    xdmp:user("admin"), 
    (),
    "normal")

let $addTask := admin:group-add-scheduled-task($config, $group, $new-task)

return admin:save-configuration($addTask)
```

Please let me know if MarkLogic defines any limit of these.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are one-time tasks, why not call [`xdmp:spawn`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:spawn) directly?

Scheduled tasks run on the task server, so at runtime they are limited by the same factors as ordinary tasks: thread count and queue size.

Your code appears to call `admin:save-configuration` 1000 times, so it doesn't surprise me that it's slow. You're also getting the initial configuration 1000 times, which is sub-optimal. Remember that a FLWOR expression evaluates the return expression for **every** item in the input sequence, as filtered by any `where` expression.

The bottleneck for *creating* scheduled tasks is probably the admin API itself, which does a lot of internal validation of the new configuration. That's fine when creating a dozen new forests, but it isn't designed for fast performance of hundreds of configuration changes.

Assuming there's a reason to create scheduled tasks instead of calling `xdmp:spawn`, try something like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
  at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $group := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
let $now := current-dateTime()
let $db := xdmp:database("SampleDB")
let $modules := xdmp:database("Modules")
let $user := xdmp:user("admin")
let $_ :=
  for $i in 1 to 1000
  let $new-task := admin:group-one-time-scheduled-task(
    "/tasks/write-log.xqy", "/", $now,
    $db, $modules, $user,
    (), 'normal')
  return xdmp:set($config, admin:group-add-scheduled-task($config, $group, $new-task))
return admin:save-configuration($config)
```

But since these are one-time tasks, you're probably better off with `xdmp:spawn`. You might also look into using https://github.com/mblakele/taskbot

Comment: From your suggested code it now takes approximately 6 minutes on the same machine to create 1000 scheduled tasks. But the exact scenario is that I am trying to create scheduled task from within the CPF action module whenever a new document is inserted.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493186/unable-to-create-mark-logic-scheduled-tasks-from-within-cpf-action-module/26494107#26494107

Comment: The problem that I am trying to solve is: I have multiple documents entering the MarkLogic database at one time, say T1 and every document has a `execute-on` node in it which defines the timestamp when that document needs to be release, say T2. So, we need to find a way to hold a particular document in MarkLogic till the time that document's `execute-on` time has not arrived. Please let me know in case there is an efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: This is a separate question and I won't be able to answer it in 600 characters. I can't tell if this is a delayed-processing scenario or an embargoed-content scenario, or something else. Try to state the problem in a new question, and someone may have a much more efficient approach. If it's embargoed content, the usual approach is to build a dateTime range index and include it as a query term in every query.

Comment: I have posted a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615520/handling-embargoed-content-scenario-in-marklogic)