# Handling embargoed content scenario in MarkLogic

Tags: scheduled-tasks, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic 7 database in which several documents are inserted and every document has its own `created-on` and `released-on`. Say for example if a document is inserted into the database at *1400* hrs and its `released-on` value is *1700* hrs then I need to POST this document to an external REST service at *1700* hrs.

I have tried the following options:

1. Configure a CPF pipeline such that whenever a document is inserted it's `released-on` value is read and a **Scheduled Task** is created to trigger based on the timestamp value read from `released-on`.

   Following are the queries/ observations for this approach:

   1. Since admin configuration manipulation APIs are not transactionally protected operations I need to force a lock on some URI in order to create Scheduled Tasks from within CPF action modules running in parallel.
      For details [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493186/unable-to-create-mark-logic-scheduled-tasks-from-within-cpf-action-module)
   2. When I insert *1000* documents it takes around *20* minutes for the CPF action modules to trigger and create *1000* scheduled tasks based on the `released-on` value read from the inserted document.
   3. How can I pass the URI of the document that triggered the CPF action module to the Schedule Task which got created from within the CPF action module based on the `released-on` value read from the document?
2. Configure a CPF pipeline such that whenever a document is inserted it's `released-on` value is read and **[`xdmp:sleep()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:sleep)** is called with the milliseconds remaining between current date Time and the value of `released-on` in the document.

   Following are the queries/ observations for this approach:

   1. The Task Server threads on which the CPF action modules are triggered remain occupied and are not released when `xdmp:sleep()` is called from within them due to which at any time CPF action module is triggered for 16 maximum documents and  others remain in queue.
   2. Is there any way we can configure the sleeping thread to become inactive and let other queued action modules to get triggered and when the sleep duration has been elapsed then it again becomes active?
3. Configure a **muti-step CPF pipeline** as described [here](http://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2009-December/004200.html) in which the document keeps bouncing between two states till the time `released-on` timestamp has arrived.

   Following are the queries/ observations for this approach:

   1. Even when *30* documents were inserted the CPU utilization was observed to be 100%

In all the attempts a lot of system resources (CPU and RAM) get utilized even for as small as *1000* documents. I need to find an approach that can cater even 100K documents.

Please let me know in case there are any improvements that can be done in the above mentioned approaches or MarkLogic provides some other way to efficiently handle such scenarios.

Comment: I think options 2 & 3 will only cause you problems. A better question is why does it take 20 minutes to create 1000 scheduled tasks? Are you locking with the same URI for all inserted documents? Set log level to debug, and check the error log for DEADLOCK messages. That should give you an idea of whether your performance problem is lock-related.

Comment: @wst: Yes, I am locking with the same URI: using `xdmp:lock-for-update("/sample.xml")` The complete CPF action module is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26501156/4166972)

Comment: Inserting 1000 documents that all lock on the same URI sounds like your problem. Use a URI unique to the inserted document; then all the other tasks can run in parallel. Alternatively, look into Multi-Statement Transactions, which can serially execute expressions in separate transactions.

Comment: @wst I tried locking on the document uri for which the CPF action module was triggered using `xdmp:lock-for-update($cpf:document-uri)` but in this case when I insert multiple documents in parallel then CPF action module gets triggered for all the documents but **ONLY ONE** Schedule Task gets created. For more [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26494107/4166972)

Comment: Ah, I see now. I still suspect the problem could be too many processes contending for that lock. You could go back to your single-URI lock, and have the CPF job `xdmp:spawn` the actual work to a task. Then you would have at most N (N = Task Server Threads) tasks contending for the lock, not all 1000. Reduce N to 2 or 1 and you might get an improvement. Worth a shot.

Comment: @wst When I insert 1000 documents then also I can see that at any given time there are 16 (not all 1000) Task Server threads contending to acquire the lock. So I think using xdmp:spawn from within the CPF action module wouldn't make any difference. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can adjust the number of Task Server threads to be anything you want, and if you're not using Task Server for anything else then you could set it to 1 and let that queue for you. But 16 vs 1000 still sounds like a net win. However, if that doesn't significantly improve performance, then this is probably not a good suggestion.

Comment: @wst It seems that the bottleneck for creating scheduled tasks is probably the admin API itself, which does a lot of internal validation of the new configuration. It isn't designed for fast performance of hundreds of configuration changes which occur when I am creating scheduled tasks from the CPF action module.

Comment: Since admin commands must be serialized, it sounds like this is the best you can do if you want to process everything upfront (which would be my preference). At least in the case of a task server-based solution, you won't have to worry about timeouts. However, if that won't meet your requirements, then @DaveCassel's polling solution is a good alternative. Similarly, you could look into the Alerting API, which essentially does the same thing though different means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than CPF, you could set up a scheduled job that will run, say, every 10 minutes and look for documents that are ready to be published. That job would look for documents with `released-on` values between `fn:current-dateTime()` and the last time the job ran, which I would save in the database.

For each of those documents, you would spawn a task to POST the document, so that an error in one doesn't cause problems for the others. After looping through, save the current time in the database for the next time.

The 10-minute window can be as large or small as you like, depending on your tolerance for a little delay.

Comment: Be sure to guard against overlapping scheduled tasks. I'd do this with a sempahore: in the task, call xdmp:lock-for-update on some arbitrary URI like `/tasks/my-task-name`. That URI doesn't need to exist, but locking it will prevent multiple tasks from trying to process the same documents.

Comment: @mblakele Now I have created a Minutely Scheduled Task that looks for documents in the *entities* collection for which the `released-on` value has passed and POSTs them to the external service and moves them to *dispatched* collection. But the problem I am facing in this approach is that when creating a minutely scheduled task if I pass the [task host] (http://docs.marklogic.com/admin:group-minutely-scheduled-task#task-host) and that host is down then the scheduled task does not get executed at all. If I leave the task host empty () then the Scheduled Task gets executed on **ALL** hosts.

Comment: Is there any way I can make sure that the Minutely Schedule Task gets executed on **ANY ONE** of the hosts in a clustered environment (not any specific host) to come out of failure situation?

Comment: You could set up the task at staggered intervals on all hosts. In a ten-host cluster, each host would kick off the task once every ten minutes, with their start times offset. Throw in mblakele's semaphore to make sure there's only one at a time. Then if one host goes down, it just means you've got a two-minute long interval.

Comment: @DaveCassel Just to clarify let me explain my understanding with the help of an example: I have a *3* node cluster so I will create a scheduled task for each of the nodes that runs in every *3* minutes. Node 1 starts at 10:00, Node 2 starts at 10:01 & Node 3 starts at 10:02. Now, If the scheduled task on Node 1 runs at 10:03 and at 10:04 Node 2 was down (scheduled task was not executed) then at 10:05 scheduled task on Node 3 will execute and process the documents for which `released-on` lies between 10:03 and 10:05. Thus every failing node will add *1* minute of delay in release of a document.

Comment: @DaveCassel Correct me in case this is not how you are suggesting.

Comment: Rahul, that's it exactly. I would include semaphore's in case (for whatever reason) two of them end up running at the same time.